# How do I make another command run when a button is pressed in discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add buttons to my bot and I want another, already existing command to be executed when the button is clicked. How can this be done? For example, when you press the "1" button, "Hi" will be executed

```
    @client.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi')



@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
      embed=discord.Embed(title="text"),
      components=[
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="1")
      ]
        )
    response = await client.wait_for("button_click")
    if response.channel == ctx.channel:
```

Comment: Why not just have the handler call the function(s) you want to call?

Comment: I tried, but failed to call the function

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you were looking for (I assume you're using discord.py). I looked over the issue and noticed three issues which were:

`components=[ Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="1") ] )` Unless you're using another library I noticed that couldn't work.

As well as fixed the use if `await client.wait_for("button_click")` and changed it to `await bot.wait_for("reaction_add")` which is the correct usage.

Lastly, the if statement was not working, so I replaced it with the check function which returns a value if the user has responded with the correct `1️⃣` emoji.

```
 @client.command(pass_context = True)
    async def test(ctx):
        message = await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Text"))
        emoji = '1️⃣' # The emoji you want the bot to react with
        await message.add_reaction(emoji) # Bot reacts with that emoji you assigned
    
        def check(response, user):
            return str(response.emoji) in emoji # Checks that the user has responded with the correct emoji
    
        response, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add") # Waits for the user to react with the emoji
        await ctx.send("Hi!")
```

Hopefully this works and resolves your issue. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the command from another command. In this case though, the command is really small and you would be better off just putting it there.

See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke) in the docs, but be warned about using converters, checks, cooldowns, pre-invoke, or after-invoke hooks, as they aren't processed.

```py
@client.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi')

# then do this in a command:
# ...
    # no arguments as it is right now
    await ctx.invoke(Hi)
    # or for other commands if you need arguments
    # sample_command(ctx, number: int, string: str)
    await ctx.invoke(sample_command, 20, 'stack')
```

Comment: You would need to `await ctx.invoke()`